# Should I call Dispose method on an Image get from the Clipboard in C#

Tags: c#, dispose

In C#/.NET, the method `Clipboard.GetData()` returns an object from the Clipboard.

If the object returned implements the `IDisposable` interface (such as an instance of the class Image), is it my responsibility to call the Dispose method on it (or use the "using" construct)?

The documentation of `GetData` does not says anything particular, so I assume the Clipboard object properly disposes everything. But my assumptions might be wrong.

Comment: I had some rather bad experiences with images and Dispose. My code worked most of the time, only sometimes, it crashes (buth then rather hard). It seems that calling Dispose harmless, until the Garbage Collector actually disposes it. So I would suggest to try out calling Dispose and then immediately call `GC.Collect()`.

Comment: @UweKeim Dispose only causes problems if you have code around that still uses the disposed objects. A typical example is people forgetting to clear some control's `Image` property before disposing the image, or, god forbid, calling `ctrl.Image.Dispose()` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispose method is supposed to be done if you use some unmanaged resources (file handles, unmanaged memory, etc). In such cases you should implement IDisposable and release resources in Dispose method.

Since you use GetData which return native .NET Object, you don't have to call Dispose method.

[An example is provided here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getdata).

Comment: Images might be using some unmanaged memory too, because of how the GDI is working

Comment: The fact that a .net object implements `IDisposable` is generally an indication that *someone* should dispose it.  The essential question in this case is whether `GetData()` simply returns a reference to an image which is owned by the clipboard, and which the clipboard will dispose, or whether it creates a new image based upon data in the clipboard, and expects the recipient of the image to dispose it.  In fact, it exhibits the latter behavior (if one calls `GetData()` twice consecutively, one will observe that different object instances are returned).

Comment: `GetData` with one argument (and, for that matter, `GetImage`) internally call `GetData` with an added argument `autoConvert = true`, which led me to the suspicion that it might create a new object on each call. To test this, I performed `ReferenceEquals` on two consecutive calls of `DataObject.GetImage()`, and the objects **were not the same**, and disposing one **did not affect the other**. This means the image is _not_ one single internal clipboard object, but created at the moment of the request, meaning `Dispose` **should be called** on it after you're done with them.

Answer (score 2):

If I really wanted to be sure, I'd look into the GetData() function with .NET Reflector to see what it does. I'm guessing it creates a copy of the image in the application's memory. So propably you need to dispose of it. Even if you don't need to, multiple dispose calls don't hurt.

Comment: As an alternative approach to answering this sort of question, call GetData twice and see if you get the same object or different objects.  If you get the same object, you can't safely dispose it or else anyone who in future grabs the clipboard will get a disposed image (oops).  If you get different objects, you can and should dispose of them.  Note that some GDI things are weird.  Controls, for example, don't care of their "Font" property is disposed (even if it's disposed before it's set!) but one can't draw with a disposed Font object.

Answer (score 2):

Questions like these are tricky. The general rule is that the owner of the `IDisposable` object is responsible for calling `Dispose`. When I see a method like `GetData` I immediately think that it's intended semantics are to transfer ownership of the `IDisposable` object from the callee to the caller. So, yes, I would assume that you are responsible. Now, on the other hand, if it were instead a property called `Data` I would then assume that ownership still belongs to the containing object because a property has the general semantics of providing access to a held instance. The problem is that API developers are often inconsistent in defining who the owner is and that is why I say questions like these are tricky. But, again, I think it is safe to assume that you should be calling `Dispose` in this case.